# Gatling, how can I make more than one virtual users to split the records in a csv feeder

Tags: csv, split, gatling

I'm trying to have a Galting script to load data to db from a csv file.

### code:

```
val feeder = csv(auctionCSVFile)

  val loder = scenario("loader").foreach(feeder.records, "record")(feed(feeder).exec { session => constructRecord(session) }.exec(PostRecord))

   setUp(
    loder.inject(rampUsers(numUsers).throttle(reachRps(maxTPS) in (rampTime seconds), holdFor(duration seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

---

if I have more than one user(numUsers>1), there will be duplication - basically each user will process the entire records.

how can i achieve that in gatling - have multiple users split the records from a csv feeder?

Comment: Looks like you are explicitly forcing each user to process the entire record with that foreach-loop. Try rebuilding your scenario without the foreach-loop, using feeders already do what you want it to do by default.